# Lightbox with SWF video

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I'm trying to use fancybox to display 2 SWF videos.

I have the issue that none of the videos are working despite the SWF being online and working using the link to it that fancybox is also using.

Can anyone have a look and help?

http://www.myofficeheadset.com/test/5_HearAndBeHeard2/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim - It might be an issue with your video. I do not know much about flash but I think it is the best starting point as your code works when using a different video link (for example, the swf used in the Fancybox website demonstration [http://www.adobe.com/jp/events/cs3_web_edition_tour/swfs/perform.swf](http://www.adobe.com/jp/))